# Value not reflecting in couchdb using putState in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: node.js, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to build a chaincode application using fabric-shim in NodeJS. When I use the putState(key,Buffer.from(value)), the value does not reflect in CouchDB, while key and other parameters (stub etc..) can be seen in CouchDB.
Any erason why it does not work?

Comment: You should try to log the value before putState(key,Buffer.from(value)). May be the value is empty/null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you look at CouchDB document, it won't show the value of a respective key. But you can see there is one attachment with a document which has actually byte array or buffer value of a key.

Please check the following image to see example attachment, if you click on it will get download as a binary file.

[image]

If you wanna fetch exact value then use the following script to get the database dump

https://github.com/danielebailo/couchdb-dump

So after database dump, you will get to see JSON object with data as one of the key in it as follows

```
{
  "_id": <<id>>,
  "_rev": <<rev>>,
  "~version": <<version>>,
  "_attachments": {
    "valueBytes": {
      "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
      "revpos": 1,
      "digest": <<key>>,
      "data": "AAAHAQA="  ==> <<value in Base64 format>>
    }
  }
}
```

Using Base64 decoder you can decode value which will return value in form of byte array or buffer. Then you can convert byte array or buffer to respective object.